# BigQuery SQL running arithmetic balance view

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables which I'd like to join to get to the desired view below:

Table 1: Contracts

| Contracts* | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Contract 1 | 10 |
| Contract 2 | 20 |
| Contract 3 | 30 |

Table 2: Deliveries

| Date | Vehicle* | Contracts | Delivered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | Vehicle A | Contract 1 | 5 |
| 02/01/2022 | Vehicle B | Contract 1 | 5 |
| 02/01/2022 | Vehicle B | Contract 2 | 10 |
| 03/01/2022 | Vehicle C | Contract 2 | 10 |
| 03/01/2022 | Vehicle C | Contract 3 | 15 |

Desired view (shows the current outstanding quantity, to be offset against the delivery for that particular contract)

`*` - Denotes primary key for that table

| Date | Vehicle | Contracts | Quantity | Outstanding | Delivered | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | Vehicle A | Contract 1 | 10 | 10 | 5 | 5 |
| 02/01/2022 | Vehicle B | Contract 1 | 10 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 02/01/2022 | Vehicle B | Contract 2 | 20 | 20 | 10 | 10 |
| 03/01/2022 | Vehicle C | Contract 2 | 20 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 03/01/2022 | Vehicle C | Contract 3 | 30 | 30 | 15 | 15 |

```
select

  deliveries.date,
  deliveries.vehicle, 
  contracts.contracts,
  contracts.quantity,
  outstanding (?),
  contracts.quantity - contracts.delivered as delivered
  balance (?)

from contracts
left join deliveries on deliveries.contracts = contracts.contracts
```

I am not sure how to write the expression for outstanding and balance.

Does it involve `sum(quantity - delivered) over (partition by vehicle order by contract)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select date, vehicle, contracts, quantity, 
  quantity - ifnull(sum(delivered) over prev, 0) outstanding, 
  delivered, 
  quantity - delivered - ifnull(sum(delivered) over prev, 0)  balance
from deliveries d 
left join contracts c
using (contracts)
window prev as (partition by contracts order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]